# Why this shell regular can't match

Tags: shell

I don't know Why this shell regular (Line 2) can't match, who can give official links to explain this?

```
$ str="origin/HEAD -> origin/master"
$ if [[ $str =~ '*origin\/HEAD*' ]] ; then echo OK ; fi # why can't work ???
$ if [[ $str =~ .*origin\/HEAD.* ]] ; then echo OK ; fi
OK
$ reg='.*origin\/HEAD.*'
$ if [[ $str =~ $reg ]] ; then echo OK ; fi # what's different of Line 2 ???
OK
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes

Answer (score 0):

When you add `set -x` to your code, you get more info:

```
+ [[ origin/HEAD -> origin/master =~ \*origin\\/HEAD\* ]]
+ [[ origin/HEAD -> origin/master =~ .*origin/HEAD.* ]]
+ echo OK
OK
+ reg='.*origin\/HEAD.*'
+ [[ origin/HEAD -> origin/master =~ .*origin\/HEAD.* ]]
```

The special characters in the assignment are used as normal characters inside single quotes. You see additional backslashes in the first line, avoiding expansion by the shell.
Your `reg=` also uses single quotes. When you use `$reg` the wildcards are expanded again.
Perhaps look at another example:

```
reg='ls *'
echo "reg (unquoted)="${reg}
echo "reg (quoted)  =${reg}"
```